# npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @typescript-eslint/parser@5.4.0

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, package.json

I am trying to install eslint parser, and this is the error I am facing.
Although `"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.4.0"` has been added in the package.json,

I am not able to build the package.

I tried deleting package-lock.json, and still it is the same.

Can I delete the node_modules folder and try again? What could I do to overcome this error?

Answer (score 0):

The version you are trying might not be available on the registry. Try downgrading to a different version and then install again.